# Converting react.js to html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

don't misunderstand. I need this for a small experiment, and since I'm not a front-end developer, I don't know react.js, I need help

I have main.jsx file
I would like to change it to pure html\css\js, i.e. without react. I have a problem. If in this code, the data from the form is transmitted to the server via const Main (if I'm not mistaken), then how to write it in html? Using the data-value attribute?

Main.jsx File:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import styles from "../styles/Main.module.css";

const FIELDS = {
  NAME: "name",
  ROOM: "room",
};

const Main = () => {
  const { NAME, ROOM } = FIELDS;

  const [values, setValues] = useState({ [NAME]: "", [ROOM]: "" });

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const isDisabled = Object.values(values).some((v) => !v);

    if (isDisabled) e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrap}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1 className={styles.heading}>Join</h1>

        <form className={styles.form}>
          <div className={styles.group}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={values[NAME]}
              placeholder="Username"
              className={styles.input}
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete="off"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.group}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="room"
              placeholder="Room"
              value={values[ROOM]}
              className={styles.input}
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete="off"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <Link
            className={styles.group}
            onClick={handleClick}
            to={`/chat?name=${values[NAME]}&room=${values[ROOM]}`}
          >
            <button type="submit" className={styles.button}>
              Sign In
            </button>
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: The form (element) isn't really being using for anything here (except to bring some structure to the input elements - input elements don't _need_ a form element). The form doesn't submit anything to a server. All that happens is when the button is clicked the app routes to a new route using the values the client has entered into the `name` and `room` inputs (values which are stored in state).

Comment: @Andy Aha, then I misunderstood that part of the code. I parsed the file with routes and there is only about what goes into the next file called /Chat and displays it. It passes the user's name and room - the name of the room. From the fact that users must enter one room name to start chatting, I start thinking. How else can data be transmitted? This project is not mine, but as I said earlier, this is a small experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best if you forget about how React (a single-page application) does this and go back to basics and work with how native form controls in a multi-page site work.

In its simplest form you need one page (`index.html`) that contains the form. The `form` element would have an `action` attribute that would route to a new page (`chat.html`).

When the submit button is clicked the form redirects to `chat.html` with the completed input values as query parameters.

You can then use JavaScript to disassemble the current URL (including its query parameters).

##### index.html

```
<form action="chat.html">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="room" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

##### chat.html

```
<script>

    // Create a new URL instance using the current URL string
    const url = new URL(window.location);

    // Get the query params
    const params = url.searchParams;

    // And then get each param by name
    console.log(params.get('name'));
    console.log(params.get('room'));
</script>
```

Additional documentation

- [Retrieving query parameters](https://stackabuse.com/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/)